# In Firefox, my general.useragent.override is not showing up correctly on "what's my user agent" sites

Tags: firefox, user-agent

Using Firefox on a Mac. I've got

general.useragent.override  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0

but when I go to "what is my user agent" sites, it shows up as

Your user agent
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:114.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0

why is the version wrong? How do I change the 114.0 to the number I want?

Comment: Bingo!! that works.  A site still says "Your web browser looks like:
Firefox on macOS" but it reports as "Firefox 121 on Linux" so there's still something my browser is leaking, but it's much better than before, this is a good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting *general.useragent.override* manually might work in some versions of Firefox, it might no longer be respected in the current version (on this PC, v. 121.0, that setting is not in *about:config*).

However, there are third-party extensions, such as [User-Agent Switcher and Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/), which can be used to change the *useragent* string, and sites such as [Am I Unique](https://amiunique.org/fingerprint), [DeviceInfo.me](https://www.deviceinfo.me/) and [others](https://privacybee.com/blog/browser-fingerprinting/) show that the string has been successfully modified.

As with any software, check reviews (e.g., does Mozilla [recommend it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-badges?utm_content=promoted-addon-badge&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=addons.mozilla.org)?)  before installing.